# Open Notification activity when clicked on Notification with firebase

Tags: java, android, firebase, notifications, firebase-cloud-messaging

I want the Notification to open Notification.class activity instead of MainActivity. I have changed code to:

```
Intent intent = new Intent(this, Notification.class);
```

But still when notification is received and clicked it open MainActivity.
I have looked  many example but couldn't get where I need to change to get another activity instead of MainActivity.

Notification is sent from firebase console as user segment.

```
import android.app.NotificationManager;
import android.app.PendingIntent;
import android.content.Context;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.graphics.Color;
import android.media.RingtoneManager;
import android.net.Uri;
import android.support.v4.app.NotificationCompat;
import android.util.Log;

import com.firebase.jobdispatcher.FirebaseJobDispatcher;
import com.firebase.jobdispatcher.GooglePlayDriver;
import com.firebase.jobdispatcher.Job;
import com.google.firebase.messaging.FirebaseMessagingService;
import com.google.firebase.messaging.RemoteMessage;

public class MyFirebaseMessagingService extends FirebaseMessagingService {

    private static final String TAG = "MyFirebaseMsgService";

    /**
     * Called when message is received.
     *
     * @param remoteMessage Object representing the message received from Firebase Cloud Messaging.
     */
    // [START receive_message]
    @Override
    public void onMessageReceived(RemoteMessage remoteMessage) {
               // TODO(developer): Handle FCM messages here.
        Log.d(TAG, "From: " + remoteMessage.getFrom());

        // Check if message contains a data payload.
        if (remoteMessage.getData().size() > 0) {
            Log.d(TAG, "Message data payload: " + remoteMessage.getData());

            if (/* Check if data needs to be processed by long running job */ true) {
                // For long-running tasks (10 seconds or more) use Firebase Job Dispatcher.
                scheduleJob();
            } else {
                // Handle message within 10 seconds
                handleNow();
            }

        }

        // Check if message contains a notification payload.
        if (remoteMessage.getNotification() != null) {
            Log.d(TAG, "Message Notification Body: " + remoteMessage.getNotification().getBody());
        }


    }

    private void scheduleJob() {
        // [START dispatch_job]
        FirebaseJobDispatcher dispatcher = new FirebaseJobDispatcher(new GooglePlayDriver(this));
        Job myJob = dispatcher.newJobBuilder()
                .setService(MyJobService.class)
                .setTag("my-job-tag")
                .build();
        dispatcher.schedule(myJob);
        // [END dispatch_job]
    }

    /**
     * Handle time allotted to BroadcastReceivers.
     */
    private void handleNow() {
        Log.d(TAG, "Short lived task is done.");
    }

    /**
     * Create and show a simple notification containing the received FCM message.
     *
     * @param messageBody FCM message body received.
     */
    private void sendNotification(String messageBody) {
        Intent intent = new Intent(this, MainActivity.class);
        intent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP);
        PendingIntent pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(this, 0 /* Request code */, intent,
                PendingIntent.FLAG_ONE_SHOT);

        Uri defaultSoundUri= RingtoneManager.getDefaultUri(RingtoneManager.TYPE_NOTIFICATION);

        NotificationCompat.Builder notificationBuilder = new NotificationCompat.Builder(this)
                .setSmallIcon(R.drawable.notification_bg)
                .setContentTitle("FCM Message")
                .setVibrate(new long[] { 1000, 1000, 1000, 1000, 1000 })
                .setLights(Color.RED, 3000, 3000)
                .setContentText(messageBody)
                .setAutoCancel(true)
                .setSound(defaultSoundUri)
                .setContentIntent(pendingIntent);

        NotificationManager notificationManager =
                (NotificationManager) getSystemService(Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);

        notificationManager.notify(0 /* ID of notification */, notificationBuilder.build());
    }
}
```

Comment: can you add the code that you use to send notification?

Comment: The intent you are using belongs to `MainActivitiy.class`. See this line in your code, inside `sendNotification()` :  `Intent intent = new Intent(this, MainActivity.class);`. Change it to `Notification.class`

Comment: I send notification through firebase for now ,
yes I have changed it to Intent intent = new Intent(this, Notification.class); Still mainActivity show up

Comment: You send notification from firebase console or from API?

Comment: firebase console

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Probably is that, change intent to this:

```
 Intent intent = new Intent(this, Notification.class);
```

So to **clarify** you from **firebase console** is not possible to open other activity than MainActivity only from the API.

**Why**:

Because of two things.

**one**:

The notifications sent from the console not fire onMessageReceived().

**Two**:

the firebase cosole notifications not have the possibily to set click actions.

**Way to fix**:

Send notifications from API and set click_actions.

Example:

```
<?php



#API access key from Google API's Console



    define( 'API_ACCESS_KEY', 'YOUR_API_KEY');



    $topic = "/topics/todos";



$url = 'https://fcm.googleapis.com/fcm/send';

$fields = array (

        'to' => $topic,

        'notification' => array (

                "body" => "nova casa adicionada",

                "title" => "Nova casa",

                "sound"=> "default",

                "click_action"=> "Notification"

        ),

        'data' => array(

            "localcasa" => "Porto",

            "precocasa"=> "1.600.000 €",

            "imgurl"=> "http://brunoferreira.esy.es/imgsandroid/casa10.jpg",

            "infocs"=> "Apartamento localizado em local premium da cidade do Porto, à Avenida Marechal Gomes da Costa, onde pode viver-se com toda a calma e descontração. No ponto mais elevado da Foz, com vista de mar e uma envolvente de luxo, rodeado por moradias, com exteriores amplos e vistas deslumbrantes. É constituída por 4 quartos, 5 casas de banho e uma garagem em que tem a capacidade para 2 carros.",

            "csid"=> "10"

        )

);

$fields = json_encode ( $fields );

$headers = array (

        'Authorization: key=' . API_ACCESS_KEY,

        'Content-Type: application/json'

);



$ch = curl_init ();

curl_setopt ( $ch, CURLOPT_URL, $url );

curl_setopt ( $ch, CURLOPT_POST, true );

curl_setopt ( $ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, $headers );

curl_setopt ( $ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true );

curl_setopt ( $ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $fields );



$result = curl_exec ( $ch );

curl_close ( $ch );



?>
```

And to set **click_ action**, in **android manifest** set this inside **notification actifity**:

```
<intent-filter>
                <action android:name="Notification" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />

            </intent-filter>
```

Comment: I updated my answer with the explanation of your problem @DreamDeveloper

Comment: any usefull resouces that I can make API

Comment: see my updated answer with the API implementation @DreamDeveloper

Comment: If I use google api  service can I upload all in one or I can use Postman

Answer (score 1):

> json that sending from the server to the app

```
{

   "notification": {
   "title": "Title",
   "text": "notification",
   "icon": "ic_launcher",
   "click_action": "NOTIFICATION_ACTIVITY"
   }
}
```

> put this in Android Menifest :

```
<activity
          android:name=".acitivy.MainActivity"
          android:screenOrientation="portrait"
          android:theme="@style/AppTheme" >

        <intent-filter>
           <action android:name="NOTIFICATION_ACTIVITY" />

           <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT"/>
        </intent-filter>

</activity>
```

> And in your MyFirebaseMessagingService.class in sendNotification method add following:

```
private void sendNotification(RemoteMessage remoteMessage, String messageBody) {
    Intent intent = new Intent(this, MainActivity.class);

    **//Add this line**
    Map<String, String> extra = remoteMessage.getData();
    for (Map.Entry<String, String> entry : extra.entrySet()) {
        intent.putExtra(entry.getKey(), entry.getValue());
    }

    intent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP);
    PendingIntent pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(this, 0, intent, PendingIntent.FLAG_ONE_SHOT);

    Uri defaultSoundUri= RingtoneManager.getDefaultUri(RingtoneManager.TYPE_NOTIFICATION);
    NotificationCompat.Builder notificationBuilder = new NotificationCompat.Builder(this)
            .setDefaults(Notification.DEFAULT_ALL)
            .setSmallIcon(Build.VERSION.SDK_INT > 20 ?  R.drawable.notification_icon_white : R.mipmap.ic_launcher_normal)
            //.setLargeIcon(Build.VERSION.SDK_INT > 20 ?  BitmapFactory.decodeResource(getResources(), R.drawable.notification_icon_white) : BitmapFactory.decodeResource(getResources(), R.mipmap.ic_launcher_normal))
            .setContentTitle(getString(R.string.app_name))
            .setDefaults(NotificationCompat.DEFAULT_SOUND | NotificationCompat.DEFAULT_VIBRATE | NotificationCompat.DEFAULT_LIGHTS)
            .setColor(ContextCompat.getColor(this, R.color.colorPrimary))
            .setPriority(Notification.PRIORITY_HIGH)
            .setContentText(messageBody)
            .setAutoCancel(true)
            .setStyle(new NotificationCompat.BigTextStyle().bigText(messageBody))
            .setDefaults(Notification.DEFAULT_LIGHTS | Notification.DEFAULT_SOUND)
            .setSound(defaultSoundUri)
            .setContentIntent(pendingIntent);

    NotificationManager notificationManager = (NotificationManager) getSystemService(Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);

    notificationBuilder.build().flags |= Notification.FLAG_AUTO_CANCEL;
    notificationManager.notify(getID(), notificationBuilder.build());
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Modify the code in your `sendNotifcation` method. As you can see you have written `MainAcitivity.class` instead of `NotificationActivity.class`. I guess thats a typo

```
  /** 
     * Create and show a simple notification containing the received FCM message. 
     * 
     * @param messageBody FCM message body received. 
     */ 
    private void sendNotification(String messageBody) {
        Intent intent = new Intent(this, NotificationActivity.class);
        intent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP);
        PendingIntent pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(this, 0 /* Request code */, intent,
                PendingIntent.FLAG_ONE_SHOT);

        Uri defaultSoundUri= RingtoneManager.getDefaultUri(RingtoneManager.TYPE_NOTIFICATION);

        NotificationCompat.Builder notificationBuilder = new NotificationCompat.Builder(this)
                .setSmallIcon(R.drawable.notification_bg)
                .setContentTitle("FCM Message") 
                .setVibrate(new long[] { 1000, 1000, 1000, 1000, 1000 }) 
                .setLights(Color.RED, 3000, 3000)
                .setContentText(messageBody)
                .setAutoCancel(true) 
                .setSound(defaultSoundUri)
                .setContentIntent(pendingIntent);

        NotificationManager notificationManager =
                (NotificationManager) getSystemService(Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);

        notificationManager.notify(0 /* ID of notification */, notificationBuilder.build());
    }
```

Comment: I have tried       
  Intent intent = new Intent(this, NotificationActivity.class);
but not working

Answer (score 0):

I did not find a call to `sendNotification()` in the code you provided. I am quite sure that the notification you see is from **Firebase** instead of from `sendNotification()` .  See on [this page](https://firebase.google.com/docs/cloud-messaging/android/topic-messaging). If your application is in background and notification payload contains notification part then your notification is delivered to system tray which on click launches Launcher activity passing any data from notification to Launcher activity in the form of bundle.

To solve your problem send only data messages and call `sendNotification()` at appropriate place in `onMessageReceived()` with intent for `Notification.class`.